# changing boundfield visible status based on viewport

Tags: c#, viewport, visible, boundfield

I have a gridview with a number of boundfields. I'm trying to make it so that some boundfields are visible or invisible depending on the width of the screen. I've looked everywhere, and i tried `visible="<%=javascript:widthFunction()%>"` where

```
        function widthFunction(){
            viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
            if(viewportWidth > "500")
                return true;
            else {return false;}
```

Clearly that's not working. I tried putting similar code in my code behind, but that requires the DataBind thing, which that won't work because

> Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have
>       a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField does not have a DataBinding
>       event.

How can this be solved?